# How do I stop the ambient light sensor from dimming my screen?

Tags: windows-8

The ambient light sensor (ALS) within the Intel Sensor Hub device on my Intel-branded Ultrabook keeps dimming my screen. It does not react to manual screen brightness changes. Is there a way to disable it?

I'm running Windows 8 RTM.

Comment: Does it show up in Device Manager as a separate device? If it does, you could try disabling it. If it's not separate, what other sensors are there and do you need them?

Comment: It's a part of a larger group of sensors called Intel Sensor Hub, disabling the sensor individually is not possible because it shows up as a single device.

Comment: Who is the manufacturer?  Sony? Asus? Toshiba?

Comment: @corwin01 - it's Intel branded ultrabook development kit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Metro Settings. General Tab. Scroll down and you will see automatic brightness. Just turn it off

Answer (score 1):

Try to put some tape over the sensor?

Have you tried to disable the [service](http://batcmd.com/windows/8/services/sensrsvc/)?

1. Run the services panel by typing in <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and running `services.msc`
2. Find the `Sensor Monitoring Service` and go to the properties menu by right clicking
3. In the `general` tab you should find an option to set the `startup type` field to disabled
4. Restart and let us know how it went!

Comment: Thanks. This is a partial solution - while stopping the service Disabling the services.msc manages to restore the screen brightness, but it also kills off other sensors (accelerometer, gyro, etc.)

Putting the tape on the sensor is a good solution in case everything else fails.